# Element that keeps proportional width and height

Tags: html, css, image

In html when you have an image and it's set to 100% width, the height of this element automatically stays proportionate. I'm looking for element that can mimmick this functionality without the image. I was thinking about using a transparent image but this seems like it's something that should be possible with css.

**Not looking for a javascript solution**

Comment: What kind of code have you tried?

Comment: @Riskbreaker I don't think this is possible, so nothing.

Comment: background-cover was my thought but given this is an image...

Comment: You mean like `height=50% of width`?  If it is the only way I know is faking with `padding` or `margin`

Comment: I'm confuse wouldn't you just need `height: auto;` ? I might be reading this wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/06/26/proportional-resizing-of-web-page-elements-using-only-css/).

I boiled it down to this http://jsfiddle.net/47amX/

```
<style>
.scaling-img {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.outer {
    margin:10px;
    max-height:340px;
    max-width:340px;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <img class="scaling-img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP7//wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [possible](http://jsfiddle.net/3KWsg/1/) using the newly introduced [viewport percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) (with some limitations).

```
div {
    background-color: peru;
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
}
```

There are four possible units:

1. `1vh` - relative to one percent of the viewport's height.
2. `1vw` - same as above, but relative to the viewport's width.
3. `1vmin` - this is equal to either `vh` or `vw`, whichever happens to be smaller.
4. `1vmax` - same as above, but equal to the max of either `vh` or `vw`

The only caveat is [browser support](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units). The `vmin` & `vmax` units aren't supported until IE11 and the `vh` and `vw` lengths are supported in IE9+ but were only recently implemented in mobile browsers. iOS7 also apparently has problems rendering the `vh` unit.

Comment: Didn't even know about this, thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

The answer: It's impossible without image or javascript

Comment: Right, making all the images to a fixed size would have been painful. I found a css solution that allows me to make images with pixel values.